# Logical circuit for priority resolution in interrupt controllers (with configurable priority, not fixed)

Tags: circuits, cpu, digital-circuits

I'm interested in what the typical solution is for priority resolution in interrupt controllers. I assume a hardware logic circuit is used, and not software. For interrupt controllers with fixed priority (by line ID), there is documentation easily available, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_encoder and https://www.righto.com/2023/02/8086-interrupt.html. But, for configurable priority, I cannot find anything. I assume a "less-than-or-equal" comparator is used (since priority value tends to be inverted, the lower the value the higher the priority. ) I designed one myself (image below), that shows four interrupt lines with 4-bit priority values, but I would be very interested in some real-world solutions, either schematics or descriptions, or, anything about how the priority resolution is typically done.

[image]